# Ethernet-bridged OpenVPN server not accepting connections from outside

Tags: debian, networking, openvpn, bridge

I have configured an OpenVPN server with ethernet bridging using this [howto](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#quick) and [this page](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html) regarding ethernet bridging. The server is also running Samba, Apache and Webmin.

```
Linux klesk 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: Debian
Release:    6.0.7
Codename:   squeeze
```

The problem is that I cannot access the server from outside of the LAN. When I connect to the webmin or Samba share internally I have no problems. The configuration on the router has not been changed and is still correct. I have tried disabling the iptables firewall with the following commands (this has been restored already)

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

But still no connections from outside are allowed. I believe the problem lies with the network interfaces created for OpenVPN. When I check Webmin I get the following information:

[image]

Currently I have iptables setup as described in the [ethernet bridging setup page](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html) of OpenVPN:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

To summarize, with the current setup, as shown in the screenshot and iptables settings, I am able to connect to the server from within the LAN (SSH, Apache, Webmin, Samba, they all work) but from outside of the LAN the server isn't accepting any connections.

Comment: It maybe missing a gateway address.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. The script provided by OpenVPN apparantly doesn't copy that part from eth0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe missing a gateway address. – Salton

Thanks, that was it. The script provided by OpenVPN apparantly doesn't copy that part from eth0. – InFerNo

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the answer? Where exactly is it missing in the script? I'm also having this problem... Thanks

Comment: @mands the scripts on [this](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html) page create a br0 interface. The script automatically sets up the IP address and netmask, but nowhere does it provide the gateway. This is what I had to do myself manually. I didn't edit the script.